# Is it okay to introduce 'example' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic

Lot of terms are already present present and lot of terms are newly originating in artificial intelligence.

It may be difficult for beginners to understand new terms from definition. It may require some in-depth knowledge on that particular terms.

But, it is easy for anyone to understand from examples.

So, is it okay to introduce a tag called `example` for asking questions that require an example as an answer?

---

You can see the question: [Simple example for side information](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28628/simple-example-for-side-information) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I like this.  Go ahead and create it.  If other users have objections, we can always remove.